# How to set APP_BASE_HREF in lazy loaded module Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I know we can set our APP_BASE_HREF from `app.module.ts` using `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/app' }` but I want to make it dynamic based on the layout I'm trying to load while routing between routes.

Basically, I have multiple roles and I have created multiple layouts for each, and for each base route I want to have a different base route, so I don't have to append across the application while navigating between routes. Like in the below-mentioned code I would like to use `fs` and `st` as my base routes for different roles while shifting between my layouts. While those layout components are in their respective modules separately.

this is my `app.routing.module.ts`

```
{
    path: 'fs',
    component: FacilitatorLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'question',
        loadChildren: () => import('./mcq/question.module').then(m => m.QuestionModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'test',
        loadChildren: () => import('./tests/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'note',
        loadChildren: () => import('./notes/notes.module').then(m => m.NotesModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {
          role: ['superadmin', 'admin', 'facilitator']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'st',
    component: StudentLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./student/student.module').then(m => m.StudentModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'question',
        loadChildren: () => import('./mcq/question.module').then(m => m.QuestionModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'accounts',
        loadChildren: () => import('./user/user.module').then(m => m.UserModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have searched and tried many solutions but nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you tried putting it in lazy loaded module provider  array?

Comment: @AakashGarg yes.

Comment: it didn't work?

Comment: @AakashGarg no it's not, but my both routes are working ie., question/list and fs/question/list. but I expected output is only fs/question/list

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbxfos?file=src/app/app.component.ts  here is the link. But I was wrong I'm only able to access question/list although I have provider set to app on my lazy loaded module

Comment: so what do you want here?

Comment: your stackblitz has an error... you have a router outlet html in your student.css  file.. fix that

Comment: As I try to navigate to route question/list -> it should come as app/question/list likewise I have multiple modules whatever I set their it takes precedence of that provider and follow my route. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Stackblitz is fixed @Mike

Comment: why don't you just route to app/question/list ... i don't know why you would do what you are asking... do you use gitter or the like ... to try to understand what you are doing

Comment: Actually, I want to use the question/list route with multiple roles like fs/question/list or ad/question/list something like this based on the layout I want to navigate. @Mike

Comment: @kishore I would just start with the simple have the different routes point to the same component.  or make a questions module with its own router and then use it...

Comment: But my intention is to identify if we can set APP_BASE_URL dynamically.